# Integral of function with absolute variable

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Integrate
>   $$\int(1-3|t|)t^2dt$$
>   and how absolute variable affect on the final result if Limit $-0.5$ to $0.5$.

Comment: Split the integration into regions where $t$ is of constant sign. In this case, -0.5 to 0 and 0 to 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. You may just write
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}(1-3|t|)\:t^2\:dt&=\int_{-0.5}^0(1-3\color{red}{|t|})\:t^2\:dt+\int_0^{0.5}(1-3\color{red}{|t|})\:t^2\:dt\\\\
&=\int_{-0.5}^0(1-3\times \color{red}{(-t)})\:t^2\:dt+\int_0^{0.5}(1-3\times \color{red}{t})\:t^2\:dt
\end{align}
$$ Then it is easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function satisfies $f(t)=f(-t)$, and the integral is 2 integral from 0 to 0,5

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-0.5}^{0.5}(1-3|t|)t^2dt = 2\int_0^{0.5}(1-3|t|)t^2dt \text{ (even function in symmetric limits) }= {2\int_0^{0.5}(1-3t)t^2dt} = \dots$$